# jQuery does not block the form from submission when user clicks on "Enter" on the keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I don't want to have my form get submitted regularly. I want it to be ajax.

I have written a code to prevent the form submission either when user clicks the button or presses the "Enter", and submit it via ajax.

It works for the button, but when the user hits Enter on the keyboard the form submits and redirects.

Here is what I have written:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keypress', function(event){
if( event.which == 13)
{
                var container = $('#pricetable'),
        loader = $("<div>",{
            "class" : "ajax-loader"
            }),                                           
        container.html(loader).show();
                $("#seenform").ajaxSubmit({
                url : "../controllers/ctr.orders.php",
                success: function( responseText, statusText, xhr )
                 {
                     loader.remove();
                     var data = responseText;
                     container.html( data );
                 }
});
console.log(responseText);
return false;
} // end of event.which if
     });
});
</script>
```

Not that, when I use following code it does not gets redirected, however I need it to send the ajax as well:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keypress', function(event){
if( event.which == 13)
{

console.log(responseText);
return false;
} // end of event.which if
     });
});
</script>
```

The two code blocks only differ in their ajax part. in the second code block I still have not added the ajax-sending part.

Comment: Maybe you should use `.on('submit')` to catch all methods of submitting.

Comment: nope, doesn't matter, still gets redirected

Answer (score 2):

you need to call `event.preventDefault();` which aborts the button click called via enter.

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(event){
    if( event.which == 13) {
      ...
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: does nothing. It also gets redirected nevertheless.

Comment: What about both `preventDefault()` and `return false`?

Comment: `return false` does nothing in that context. If you would like to do in this style, you need a function, which returns false in onsubmit handler on the button. E. g.: `<input type="submit" onsubmit="javascript:DoSomething();">`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue though not directly by sending an ajax request.

I solved it in this way and it worked:

when the user hots `Enter` on the keyboard, I prevent just check what type of event.which it is, if it is 13, then I `trigger()` the `click event` of the button, and then return false.

@alpham8 return false does something here as it does not let the javascript to have its natural flow.